# How to permanently obliterate android phone's entire data?

Tags: data-recovery, mobile-data, delete, data

I want to completely delete all data on my android phone with 0% of it being recoverable.
I don't want to physically destroy the phone.
I don't want to make the phone unusable.

What I want to do is, delete all data to protect my privacy.
I will continue using the phone but I will not add any personal data after I clean it.

But I want to be 100% sure that it will never be recovered again.
is there a command to achieve that? Or only physical destruction is the answer?

Comment: If `/data` isn't encrypted, physical damage is the only way. Also see my comment [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/244461#comment325673_244461) and other links provided in the comment.

Comment: @IrfanLatif , ye I did root the phone. I think this is what you meant by "isn't encrypted" right?

Comment: No "not encrypted" can be taken literally and has nothing to to with root. Modern Android device do encrypt all user data by default, on older phones you had to manually enable encryption. See Android settings -> Security there you can usually see if the phone is encrypted or not.

Comment: oh ok, my bad. it says "phone encrypted" indeed. does that mean I can delete data safely? and if somehow someone decrypted the phone later, will it be accessible?