# How to use /dev/urandom?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, factory-reset, data-recovery, data

As a follow up to my [previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/244733/how-to-permanently-obliterate-android-phones-entire-data),
I decided to use `/dev/urandom` to overwrite my data.
But how do I use it? where do I type that?

could you walk me into the steps to do it?
and is it better to do it on empty storage or full storage?
I mean, do I need to fill every possible space first then do it, or delete everything then do it?

Also, I actually messed up my stock recovery while trying to boot TWRP before.
My phone currently does not boot into recovery whatsoever.
IS it safe to do a factory reset? And will it perform `TRIM` or not?

I apologize if this sounds dumb, but I don't understand much about The "underground" of android.

My device is android 7.1.1 (rooted)
I have ADB installed on my PC

Comment: *'cat /dev/urandom > /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata'* with root permissions from recovery terminal will overwrite whole block partition (may take hours)

Comment: Alternatively use `cat /dev/urandom > /sdcard/somefilename` to overwrite the free disc space (works without root permissions).

Comment: As you confirmed in your previous question that your phone is encrypted, so shredding isn't needed. Everything written to physical storage must already be junk. That's the whole purpose of encryption.